# Reducing running time of creating integration field in flow field algorithm (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The integration field needs to get recalculated every time the starting or goal coordinates change. I wanted to use the flow field algorithm for a problem that includes bigger mazes with changing starting or ending points every 0.5 seconds. Right now the algorithm is far too slow to be useful because the integration field needs to get recalculated every time the starting or ending point changes.

Has someone an idea how to reduce the running time of the method `create_integration_field` in class `FlowField`? I'm glad about every hint! (If you are good with numpy, I'd appreciate a possible solution using it, too.) Thank you in advance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

show_animation = True


def draw_horizontal_line(start_x, start_y, length, o_x, o_y, o_dict, path):
    for i in range(start_x, start_x + length):
        for j in range(start_y, start_y + 2):
            o_x.append(i)
            o_y.append(j)
            o_dict[(i, j)] = path


def draw_vertical_line(start_x, start_y, length, o_x, o_y, o_dict, path):
    for i in range(start_x, start_x + 2):
        for j in range(start_y, start_y + length):
            o_x.append(i)
            o_y.append(j)
            o_dict[(i, j)] = path


class FlowField:
    def __init__(self, obs_grid, goal_x, goal_y, start_x, start_y,
                 limit_x, limit_y):
        self.start_pt = [start_x, start_y]
        self.goal_pt = [goal_x, goal_y]
        self.obs_grid = obs_grid
        self.limit_x, self.limit_y = limit_x, limit_y
        self.cost_field = {}
        self.integration_field = {}
        self.vector_field = {}

    def find_path(self):
        self.create_cost_field()
        self.create_integration_field()
        self.assign_vectors()
        self.follow_vectors()

    def create_cost_field(self):
        """Assign cost to each grid which defines the energy
        it would take to get there."""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                if self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'free':
                    self.cost_field[(i, j)] = 1
                elif self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'medium':
                    self.cost_field[(i, j)] = 7
                elif self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'hard':
                    self.cost_field[(i, j)] = 20
                elif self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'obs':
                    continue

                if [i, j] == self.goal_pt:
                    self.cost_field[(i, j)] = 0

    def create_integration_field(self):
        """Start from the goal node and calculate the value
        of the integration field at each node. Start by
        assigning a value of infinity to every node except
        the goal node which is assigned a value of 0. Put the
        goal node in the open list and then get its neighbors
        (must not be obstacles). For each neighbor, the new
        cost is equal to the cost of the current node in the
        integration field (in the beginning, this will simply
        be the goal node) + the cost of the neighbor in the
        cost field + the extra cost (optional). The new cost
        is only assigned if it is less than the previously
        assigned cost of the node in the integration field and,
        when that happens, the neighbor is put on the open list.
        This process continues until the open list is empty."""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                if self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'obs':
                    continue
                self.integration_field[(i, j)] = np.inf
                if [i, j] == self.goal_pt:
                    self.integration_field[(i, j)] = 0

        open_list = [(self.goal_pt, 0)]
        while open_list:
            curr_pos, curr_cost = open_list[0]
            curr_x, curr_y = curr_pos
            for i in range(-1, 2):
                for j in range(-1, 2):
                    x, y = curr_x + i, curr_y + j
                    if self.obs_grid[(x, y)] == 'obs':
                        continue
                    if (i, j) in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
                        e_cost = 10
                    else:
                        e_cost = 14
                    neighbor_energy = self.cost_field[(x, y)]
                    neighbor_old_cost = self.integration_field[(x, y)]
                    neighbor_new_cost = curr_cost + neighbor_energy + e_cost
                    if neighbor_new_cost < neighbor_old_cost:
                        self.integration_field[(x, y)] = neighbor_new_cost
                        open_list.append(([x, y], neighbor_new_cost))
            del open_list[0]

    def assign_vectors(self):
        """For each node, assign a vector from itself to the node with
        the lowest cost in the integration field. An agent will simply
        follow this vector field to the goal"""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                if self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'obs':
                    continue
                if [i, j] == self.goal_pt:
                    self.vector_field[(i, j)] = (None, None)
                    continue
                offset_list = [(i + a, j + b)
                               for a in range(-1, 2)
                               for b in range(-1, 2)]
                neighbor_list = [{'loc': pt,
                                  'cost': self.integration_field[pt]}
                                 for pt in offset_list
                                 if self.obs_grid[pt] != 'obs']
                neighbor_list = sorted(neighbor_list, key=lambda x: x['cost'])
                best_neighbor = neighbor_list[0]['loc']
                self.vector_field[(i, j)] = best_neighbor
    
    def follow_vectors(self):
        curr_x, curr_y = self.start_pt
        while curr_x is not None and curr_y is not None:
            curr_x, curr_y = self.vector_field[(curr_x, curr_y)]
            if curr_x is None or curr_y is None:
                break

            if show_animation:
                plt.plot(curr_x, curr_y, "b*")
                plt.pause(0.001)

        if show_animation:
            plt.show()


def main():
    # set obstacle positions
    obs_dict = {}
    for i in range(51):
        for j in range(51):
            obs_dict[(i, j)] = 'free'
    o_x, o_y, m_x, m_y, h_x, h_y = [], [], [], [], [], []

    s_x = 5.0
    s_y = 5.0
    g_x = 35.0
    g_y = 45.0

    # draw outer border of maze
    draw_vertical_line(0, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_vertical_line(48, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_horizontal_line(0, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_horizontal_line(0, 48, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    # draw inner walls
    all_x = [10, 10, 10, 15, 20, 20, 30, 30, 35, 30, 40, 45]
    all_y = [10, 30, 45, 20, 5, 40, 10, 40, 5, 40, 10, 25]
    all_len = [10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 20, 10, 25, 10, 35, 15]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [35, 40, 15, 10, 45, 20, 10, 15, 25, 45, 10, 30, 10, 40]
    all_y = [5, 10, 15, 20, 20, 25, 30, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 45, 45]
    all_len = [10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    # Some points are assigned a slightly higher energy value in the cost
    # field. For example, if an agent wishes to go to a point, it might
    # encounter different kind of terrain like grass and dirt. Grass is
    # assigned medium difficulty of passage (color coded as green on the
    # map here). Dirt is assigned hard difficulty of passage (color coded
    # as brown here). Hence, this algorithm will take into account how
    # difficult it is to go through certain areas of a map when deciding
    # the shortest path.

    # draw paths that have medium difficulty (in terms of going through them)
    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [10, 45]
    all_y = [22, 20]
    all_len = [8, 5]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, m_x, m_y, obs_dict, 'medium')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [20, 30, 42] + [47] * 5
    all_y = [35, 30, 38] + [37 + i for i in range(2)]
    all_len = [5, 7, 3] + [1] * 3
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, m_x, m_y, obs_dict, 'medium')

    # draw paths that have hard difficulty (in terms of going through them)
    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [15, 20, 35]
    all_y = [45, 20, 35]
    all_len = [3, 5, 7]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, h_x, h_y, obs_dict, 'hard')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [30] + [47] * 5
    all_y = [10] + [37 + i for i in range(2)]
    all_len = [5] + [1] * 3
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, h_x, h_y, obs_dict, 'hard')

    if show_animation:
        plt.plot(o_x, o_y, "sr")
        plt.plot(m_x, m_y, "sg")
        plt.plot(h_x, h_y, "sy")
        plt.plot(s_x, s_y, "og")
        plt.plot(g_x, g_y, "o")
        plt.grid(True)

    flow_obj = FlowField(obs_dict, g_x, g_y, s_x, s_y, 50, 50)
    flow_obj.find_path()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The code, at least in terms of style, is already pretty decent. Consider:

- Add PEP484 type hints
- Your `draw_*_line` methods have a confusing name - they don't actually draw anything; they're data construction/setup routines. Also, rather than mutating `o_x`, `o_y` and `o_dict`, entirely eliminating side-effects from this function is easy - just return two lists and a dict, and at the calling side call two `extend`s and an `update`, respectively.
- `start_pt` and `goal_pt` should use tuples, not lists
- For this code:

  ```
    for i in range(self.limit_x):
        for j in range(self.limit_y):
  ```

Since it's repeated several times, consider factoring it out into a generator function that yields coordinate tuples.

- Consider replacing your `'obs'`, etc. strings with `Enum` values
- Use a set instead of a list for membership checks in `if (i, j) in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:`
- For your `neighbor_list`, rather than a weakly-typed dictionary, make a class - a `@dataclass` would suit

An implementation that does some of the above:

```
from typing import Tuple, Dict, List

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

show_animation = True


Coord = Tuple[int, int]


def draw_horizontal_line(
    start_x: int, start_y: int, length: int,
    o_x: List[int], o_y: List[int],
    o_dict: Dict[Coord, str],
    path: str,
) -> None:
    for i in range(start_x, start_x + length):
        for j in range(start_y, start_y + 2):
            o_x.append(i)
            o_y.append(j)
            o_dict[(i, j)] = path


def draw_vertical_line(
    start_x: int, start_y: int, length: int,
    o_x: List[int], o_y: List[int],
    o_dict: Dict[Coord, str],
    path: str,
) -> None:
    for i in range(start_x, start_x + 2):
        for j in range(start_y, start_y + length):
            o_x.append(i)
            o_y.append(j)
            o_dict[(i, j)] = path


class FlowField:
    def __init__(
        self,
        obs_grid: Dict[Coord, str],
        goal_x: float, goal_y: float,
        start_x: float, start_y: float,
        limit_x: int, limit_y: int,
    ):
        self.start_pt = (start_x, start_y)
        self.goal_pt = (goal_x, goal_y)
        self.obs_grid = obs_grid
        self.limit_x, self.limit_y = limit_x, limit_y
        self.cost_field: Dict[Coord, int] = {}
        self.integration_field: Dict[Coord, int] = {}
        self.vector_field: Dict[Coord, Coord] = {}

    def find_path(self) -> None:
        self.create_cost_field()
        self.create_integration_field()
        self.assign_vectors()
        self.follow_vectors()

    def create_cost_field(self) -> None:
        """Assign cost to each grid which defines the energy
        it would take to get there."""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                coord = (i, j)
                if self.obs_grid[coord] == 'free':
                    self.cost_field[coord] = 1
                elif self.obs_grid[coord] == 'medium':
                    self.cost_field[coord] = 7
                elif self.obs_grid[coord] == 'hard':
                    self.cost_field[coord] = 20
                elif self.obs_grid[coord] == 'obs':
                    continue

                if coord == self.goal_pt:
                    self.cost_field[coord] = 0

    def create_integration_field(self) -> None:
        """Start from the goal node and calculate the value
        of the integration field at each node. Start by
        assigning a value of infinity to every node except
        the goal node which is assigned a value of 0. Put the
        goal node in the open list and then get its neighbors
        (must not be obstacles). For each neighbor, the new
        cost is equal to the cost of the current node in the
        integration field (in the beginning, this will simply
        be the goal node) + the cost of the neighbor in the
        cost field + the extra cost (optional). The new cost
        is only assigned if it is less than the previously
        assigned cost of the node in the integration field and,
        when that happens, the neighbor is put on the open list.
        This process continues until the open list is empty."""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                if self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'obs':
                    continue
                self.integration_field[(i, j)] = np.inf
                if (i, j) == self.goal_pt:
                    self.integration_field[(i, j)] = 0

        open_list = [(self.goal_pt, 0)]
        while open_list:
            curr_pos, curr_cost = open_list[0]
            curr_x, curr_y = curr_pos
            for i in range(-1, 2):
                for j in range(-1, 2):
                    x, y = curr_x + i, curr_y + j
                    if self.obs_grid[(x, y)] == 'obs':
                        continue
                    if (i, j) in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
                        e_cost = 10
                    else:
                        e_cost = 14
                    neighbor_energy = self.cost_field[(x, y)]
                    neighbor_old_cost = self.integration_field[(x, y)]
                    neighbor_new_cost = curr_cost + neighbor_energy + e_cost
                    if neighbor_new_cost < neighbor_old_cost:
                        self.integration_field[(x, y)] = neighbor_new_cost
                        open_list.append(([x, y], neighbor_new_cost))
            del open_list[0]

    def assign_vectors(self) -> None:
        """For each node, assign a vector from itself to the node with
        the lowest cost in the integration field. An agent will simply
        follow this vector field to the goal"""
        for i in range(self.limit_x):
            for j in range(self.limit_y):
                if self.obs_grid[(i, j)] == 'obs':
                    continue
                if (i, j) == self.goal_pt:
                    self.vector_field[(i, j)] = (None, None)
                    continue
                offset_list = [(i + a, j + b)
                               for a in range(-1, 2)
                               for b in range(-1, 2)]
                neighbor_list = [{'loc': pt,
                                  'cost': self.integration_field[pt]}
                                 for pt in offset_list
                                 if self.obs_grid[pt] != 'obs']
                neighbor_list = sorted(neighbor_list, key=lambda x: x['cost'])
                best_neighbor = neighbor_list[0]['loc']
                self.vector_field[(i, j)] = best_neighbor

    def follow_vectors(self) -> None:
        curr_x, curr_y = self.start_pt
        while curr_x is not None and curr_y is not None:
            curr_x, curr_y = self.vector_field[(curr_x, curr_y)]
            if curr_x is None or curr_y is None:
                break

            if show_animation:
                plt.plot(curr_x, curr_y, "b*")
                plt.pause(0.001)

        if show_animation:
            plt.show()


def main():
    # set obstacle positions
    obs_dict = {}
    for i in range(51):
        for j in range(51):
            obs_dict[(i, j)] = 'free'
    o_x, o_y, m_x, m_y, h_x, h_y = [], [], [], [], [], []

    s_x = 5.0
    s_y = 5.0
    g_x = 35.0
    g_y = 45.0

    # draw outer border of maze
    draw_vertical_line(0, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_vertical_line(48, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_horizontal_line(0, 0, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')
    draw_horizontal_line(0, 48, 50, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    # draw inner walls
    all_x = [10, 10, 10, 15, 20, 20, 30, 30, 35, 30, 40, 45]
    all_y = [10, 30, 45, 20, 5, 40, 10, 40, 5, 40, 10, 25]
    all_len = [10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 20, 10, 25, 10, 35, 15]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [35, 40, 15, 10, 45, 20, 10, 15, 25, 45, 10, 30, 10, 40]
    all_y = [5, 10, 15, 20, 20, 25, 30, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 45, 45]
    all_len = [10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, o_x, o_y, obs_dict, 'obs')

    # Some points are assigned a slightly higher energy value in the cost
    # field. For example, if an agent wishes to go to a point, it might
    # encounter different kind of terrain like grass and dirt. Grass is
    # assigned medium difficulty of passage (color coded as green on the
    # map here). Dirt is assigned hard difficulty of passage (color coded
    # as brown here). Hence, this algorithm will take into account how
    # difficult it is to go through certain areas of a map when deciding
    # the shortest path.

    # draw paths that have medium difficulty (in terms of going through them)
    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [10, 45]
    all_y = [22, 20]
    all_len = [8, 5]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, m_x, m_y, obs_dict, 'medium')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [20, 30, 42] + [47] * 5
    all_y = [35, 30, 38] + [37 + i for i in range(2)]
    all_len = [5, 7, 3] + [1] * 3
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, m_x, m_y, obs_dict, 'medium')

    # draw paths that have hard difficulty (in terms of going through them)
    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [15, 20, 35]
    all_y = [45, 20, 35]
    all_len = [3, 5, 7]
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_vertical_line(x, y, l, h_x, h_y, obs_dict, 'hard')

    all_x[:], all_y[:], all_len[:] = [], [], []
    all_x = [30] + [47] * 5
    all_y = [10] + [37 + i for i in range(2)]
    all_len = [5] + [1] * 3
    for x, y, l in zip(all_x, all_y, all_len):
        draw_horizontal_line(x, y, l, h_x, h_y, obs_dict, 'hard')

    if show_animation:
        plt.plot(o_x, o_y, "sr")
        plt.plot(m_x, m_y, "sg")
        plt.plot(h_x, h_y, "sy")
        plt.plot(s_x, s_y, "og")
        plt.plot(g_x, g_y, "o")
        plt.grid(True)

    flow_obj = FlowField(obs_dict, g_x, g_y, s_x, s_y, 50, 50)
    flow_obj.find_path()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```